# ESRI ArcGIS Client match map to WKID (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight-5.0, arcgis, esri

I am using the map service at http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer, which gives me a world map.

I have a shape file (.prj) that looks like this:

PROJCS["UTM:10N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",DATUM["D_North_American_1927",SPHEROID["CLARKE 1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM["GREENWICH",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-123.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],UNIT["METER",1.0]]

The locations relevant to the shape file are in western Canada (UTM:10N).  Research seems to indicate that this is WKID 26710.

If I create the map layer and set the SpatialReference to 26710, no map shows.  If I set SpatialReference to 102100, I get a map, but my points are in eastern France.  This tells me that my reference is off.

I am processing the shape files, but I do not create or own them.  How would you go about getting them to position themselves correctly in Canada?  It seems that the answer would be to "get the right Spatial Reference", but all the searching I have done says that that is 26710.

Answer (score 1):

The map service you're using only plots geometries supplied in the 102100 projection.  If you have access to an ArcGIS Geometry server, you can convert your data points from the source projection to the one required by the map service. See http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/project.html

For example, if you have a point whose coordinates in the 26710 wkid are (491800, 5456280), you could do something like

http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=26710&outSR=102100&geometries=%7B%22geometryType%22%3A%22esriGeometryPoint%22%2C%22geometries%22%3A%5B%7B%22x%22%3A491800%2C%22y%22%3A5456280%7D%5D%7D&f=pjson

The x and y coodinates in that result should show up somewhere around Vancouver on the map service you linked.

Comment: + 1 for the example.  What I think I need, however, is a way to do the conversion without having to call a server (although I do see that I might be able to send several points in one call).  This sample geometry server indicates that it is only a sample and is subject to change or removal at any time.